# Formatting the number of data points on a graph python

Tags: python, matplotlib, forecasting

I am working with time series data trying to forecast the data using OLS. I know this is literally the most basic type of forecasting but it's what I am supposed to use. My data is hourly data for four years and I want to plot the original data against the models predictions using the training test and the models predictions using the test set. When I plot my model predictions against the original data its really tough to see anything. I have tried increasing the plot size but that's not going to help when you have like 35k points. I would like to plot just the last 500 predictions from test set against the last 500 values of my original data set. My issue I don't know how to select only a subset of rows because of how I set up my variables. **Can someone take a look at this and tell me how I can reduce the rows on the graph?**

My data frame = patients_hr

[image]

- This first 12 and the last 12 rows have NaN values in the  df so I skip them when created my test/train. Also IDK if this matters but here is how I have my matplotlib imported:

Import matplotlib

```
[IN]:
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pylab
import seaborn as sns
```

Create my training set:

```
[IN]: 
pthrs_train1 = patients_hr.iloc[12:24544,:]
```

Create my test set:

```
[IN]: 
pthrs_test1 = patients_hr.iloc[24544:35052:,:]
```

Train OLS Forecasting model
[IN]:

```
linmodel = ols('PatientsPerHR ~ trend', data = pthrs_train1).fit()
p = linmodel.params
linmodel.summary()
```

Create predictions using test set

```
[IN]:
linpred = linmodel.predict(pthrs_test1)
```

Create predictions using training set

```
[IN]:
linfit = linmodel.predict(pthrs_train1)
```

Graphing the data

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,8))
ax.plot(patients_hr['TimeStamp'], patients_hr['PatientsPerHR']) #original data
ax.plot(pthrs_test1['TimeStamp'], linpred, "r") #test set
ax.plot(pthrs_train1['TimeStamp'], linfit, "purple") #training set
ax.plot()
```

Normally I would just use .iloc but because of how I have plotted this it won't work. I have tried to change up I created the variables so I could use .iloc but I am still somewhat of a novice with python so I don't know how to change this. I have include a screen grab of my df set up.